# Web sockets or push notifications for non-native (web) applications

Tags: android, html, mobile

One of the advantages I thought of writing a HTML5 based app for mobile devices would be I wouldn't have to deal with (many) quirks.

I want to push changes from my server to a mobile phones browser, for example if my users goto http://mysite.com they should be notified when something changes. Is it possible to do this for android chrome browser and apple safari?

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible if you build a server that can handle push (typically via WebSockets).  Take a look at [socket.io](http://socket.io/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes if the changes are instant you can use websockets. Recently I started using http://pusher.com/ which is a quite good service. Alternitively create your own websockets to do this. Here is an article on websockets: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/